# SQL Server SA user locked out - how to find out who did it?

Tags: sql-server

Someone locked out the SA user on our SQL Server 2008 instance.  Is there anyway to find out who did it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server logs should show you the logon attempt failures and what machine they came from. From there, you just need to figure out who was on that particular machine.

To see the logs, just fire up management studio (or whatever it is called in 2008 these days) and look under the Management section.

[edit]

You can also see the failed logon attempts in the Application Event logs using Event Viewer

Answer (score 1):

Anybody deleted databases lately? If the SA user had their default database set to db that has been deleted that'll lock 'em out.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that someone tried a bad password too many times, but I'd like to confirm that it was just this person and not something more sinister.